# Spring conditionally instantiate Class (Restcontroller)

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to instantiate a class only if a certain property is **not present** or (if possible) if **certain profile is active**.

I tried using `@ConditionalOnProperty`. The Property is set within a yml-file:

```
some:
  service:
    address: some.adress.org
    port: 5200
```

If i start the application with profile mock the complete block is missing. Only in this case i want to instantiate a certain `@RestController`. How to achieve this?

What i tried so far was not working. Either the controller was instantiated in both cases or never.
Instantiates controller in both cases:

- `@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "some.service.address", matchIfMissing = true)`
- `@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "some.service.address", matchIfMissing = true)`

Instantiate never:

- `@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "some.service.address", matchIfMissing = true, havingValue="xyz")`
- `@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "some.service.address", matchIfMissing = true, havingValue="xyz")`

Comment: Why not simply place `@Profile("mock")` on the controller?

Comment: :-) good question. make this an answer (it is working)